# What is the correct way of accessing a Swift Delegate from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegation

Environment: Xcode 6.1.1 & Xcode 6.2 Beta

Greetings: 
I need to publish a NSString within a Swift doc from a neighboring Objective-C doc within the same project.  For example, display "Hello World" generated in Objective-C upon a Swift page.  
I've made a proof-of-concept demo; based on feedback.

I'm thinking of using an ObjC --> Swift delegate via a protocol pattern as shown below:
[image]

Note: the Swift file is the delegate.

Here I'm calling the delegate method in Swift, from Objective-C:

```
#pragma mark - Action methods
- (IBAction)sendDelegateAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    [_delegate radiusString:@"Hello World"];
}
```

I've instantiated the Objective-C file to link the delegate to the instance (I hope I got it right):

```
let geo32Controller = MyObjCTableViewController()
geo32Controller.delegate = self
```

So far, the compiler complained that the Swift protocol couldn't be found.

Here's the protocol (declared in Swift):

```
@objc protocol DiscoveryContributeProtocol {
    // optional
    func radiusString(radiusString:String)
}
```

And here's the delegate reference to that protocol in the Objective-C header file:

```
@interface MyObjCTableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DiscoveryContributeProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

However, the compiler can't find the protocol:
[image]

---

BTW: when I put the bridge reference in the ObjC's header file, I get a compiler error:

[image]

Two Questions:

1. Do I have the correct pattern (did I instantiate the ObjC correctly) ?
2. How do I make the Objective-C portion see the Swift protocol for the delegate link?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but have a few bugs that are preventing this from working.

1. You've declared `Geo32Boundaries` as conforming to the `DiscoveryContributeProtocol`, but it doesn't need to and doesn't actually implement it, it only has a *property* that conforms to that protocol. That's the source of the "Method 'radiusString:' not implemented" error:

   ```
   @interface Geo32Boundaries: UIViewController    // <-- that's all you need
   ```
2. You're setting the `delegate` incorrectly -- the code you have there looks like it's trying to set a class instance of `Geo32Boundaries` to `self`, but you're also trying to call it like a function. You'll need to set the delegate on a the *instance* of the `Geo32Boundaries` view controller that is being presented to the user. I don't know where that code lives, so I can't give a great example, but it'll be something like:

   ```
   geo32Controller.delegate = self
   ```
3. Lastly, though not a bug, your protocol should really be called `DiscoveryContributeDelegate` -- we usually don't use "protocol" in the protocol name.

Comment: Okay... I've make a proof-of-concept/demo app. with your suggested revisions (see re-written Question, above).   Am I getting close?

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee Item 1 is incorrect, the bridging header import needs to be in the obj-c header file, not the implementation file. That is why you are getting a "cannot find protocol declaration" in the interface. Personally I would put the bridging header import in your `*_prefix.h` file, then you know it's everywhere.

Comment: I've added the bridging header into the ObjC's header file.  But the compiler can't find it.  See added material to query, above.